# R - regex: W metacharacter not working when within square brackets

Tags: r, regex, square-bracket, metacharacters

Let's take the following string:

```
x <- " hello world"
```

I would like to extract the first word. To do so, I am using the following regex `^\\W*([a-zA-Z]+).*` with a back-reference to the first group.

```
> gsub("^\\W*([a-zA-Z]+).*", "\\1", x)
[1] "hello"
```

It works as expected.

Now, let's add a digit and underscore to our string:

```
x <- " 0_hello world"
```

I replace `\\W` by `[\\W_0-9]` to match the new characters.

```
> gsub("^[\\W_0-9]*([a-zA-Z]+).*", "\\1", x)
[1] " 0_hello world"
```

Now, it doesn't work and I do not understand why. It seems that the problem arises when putting `\\W` within `[]` but I am not sure why.
The regex works on [online regex tester using PCRE](https://regex101.com/r/FypKsK/1) though.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try with `sub("^[ 0-9]*([a-zA-Z]+).*", "\\1", x,)`

Comment: @akrun, the reason why I used the W metacharacter instead of a simple space is because I am dealing with many strings starting with various characters including punctuation marks, space, digits and underscore.

Comment: use the `perl = TRUE` i.e. `sub("^[\\W_0-9]*([a-zA-Z]+).*", "\\1", x, perl = TRUE)`  Here, I am using `sub` because we are only matching this once

Comment: @mt1022 `perl=TRUE` fixed the problem. Can you make it as an answer so I can accept it? Thanks.

Comment: Adding `perl=TRUE` is not a full solution. You need to add `(?s)` before the regex since in TRE, `.` matches any char while in PCRE it matches any char but line break chars.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Thanks for the additional info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick solution is to use Perl-like Regular Expressions by adding an additional argument `perl = TRUE`.

By default, `grep` use Extended Regular Expressions (see `?regex`) where character classes are defined in the format of `[:xxx:]`. However, I could not find a character class to match `\W` exactly.